# Get login details from facebook native app using php or javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, php, android, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to create `facebook login` for Mobile Browser which use facebook details from facebook native app.Using a web browser e.g. Chrome on Android, if a mobile website requires a user to be logged in to Facebook and they are not, the browser will open a popup which ask for Login details even though the phone may be logged in to Facebook via the Facebook native App. Is there any way to get details from the Facebook App without use popup window using `PHP` or `Javascript` SDK.